# Is there a word for the way this Geisha is sitting?

Tags: word-request

Is there any word for sitting like this:

[image]

> The geisha __ across from him at the tea table.

Comment: There is a word for sitting with your legs crossed, you say sitting cross-legged. However, the picture above is not someone sitting with their legs crossed!

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking whether there is a *direct* translation for the Japanese *seiza* (正座), there is not.  The closest is "to kneel" but this is not exact, as [this is considered kneeling](https://previews.123rf.com/images/tadija/tadija1003/tadija100300179/6698283-Lonely-young-girl-to-kneel-absorbed-in-thought-and-smoke-a-cigarette-Stock-Photo.jpg) as is [this](https://lifesite-cache.s3.amazonaws.com/images/made/images/news/Tim-Tebowingfp_405_245_55.jpg) and [this](https://journeytonewknees.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/kneeling.jpg).

> The geisha knelt across from him at the tea table.

You can also say "sat on (one's) heels" but it's not a very elegant phrase, and many people may not understand what you mean.