# Sitting on hams, leg, foot or what?

Tags: word-request

The way the boy is sitting in the picture says that he is sitting on his leg. But in some texts I've found that this way is called 'sitting on left foot'. However I feel if we say 'sit on left foot', it'll sound as if one is sitting on his left foot squatting.

'Sitting on hams' may be used too, not sure though. What is indeed the part this pictures shows the boy is sitting on?

i. hams

ii. foot

iii. thigh

iv. leg

v. shin

vi. heels

To me 'leg' seems to be fine.

[image]

Comment: I think all of the above are acceptable, is there any reason you think any of them wouldn't? I'm not sure there is one commonly accepted way of describing this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a word for the way this Geisha is sitting?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/141564/is-there-a-word-for-the-way-this-geisha-is-sitting)

Comment: @Bee It does seem to be a duplicate, but that question does not have an accepted answer, so what's the rule on that?

Comment: Provided it has an up-voted answer, that tends to still count as a dupe. It's only not a dupe if there are no positively voted answers (I think but I can't find the page I saw that on).

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that "hams" is a commonly used term outside of a physical fitness context, at least not in British English. A personal trainer might talk about working on your "hams", but in everyday speech, I don't believe it would be used. In any case, your *hamstrings* are the tendons *inside* your leg - the external, fleshy area of that part of the leg is called the *calf*.

I would have described the boy in the picture as *kneeling*, because his knees and shins are the only parts of his body in contact with the floor. If I wanted to be more specific about the way he is leaning back, for want of a name/expression I would probably say that *he is kneeling and leaning back on his calves*.